# Get item from Django model into HTML

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django

I want to include the title and message from every notification in the model Notifications from models.py. I don't want to have to change every single views.py that I have to do this. I know that it's possible to put the tag {% request.user.name %} to get details from the user, but how can I do this with another random model?

I have already tried some things.
These are the files that I created/changed in an attempt to do this.
(`home` is the name of my app)

`home/templatetags/__init__.py`

```
from .custom_tags import register
```

`home/templatetags/custom_tags.py`

```
from django import template
from home.models import Notifications

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def notifications():
    data = Notifications.objects.all()  
    return data
```

`home/templates/base.html`

```
{% load custom_tags %}
<html>
<head><!-- Some code here --></head>
<body>
    <!-- Some more code here -->
    {% notifications %}
    {% for notification in notifications_list %}
        {{ notification.title }}
    {% endfor %}
</body>
```

In `base.html`, the line `{% notifications %}` shows `<QuerySet [<Notifications: Notifications object (1)>]>`. But all of the other lines don't do anything.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to render html inside the custom tag with a small html template belonging to the tag and return it:

```
@register.simple_tag
def notifications():
    data = Notifications.objects.all()  
    context = {"data": data}
    return render_to_string("...../notification_tag.html", context)
```

in the base.html then just use:

```
<body>
    <!-- Some more code here -->
    {% notifications %}
</body>
```